# How to reverse complement a DNA strand using R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I am trying to reverse complement a DNA strand using R, however, my code is not working.

```
  map=c("A"="T","T"="A","G"="C","C"="G")
  r<-sapply(lapply(strsplit(y,NULL),rev),paste,collpase="")
  t<-paste(map[unlist(strsplit(r,NULL))],collapse="")
  return(t)}
```

This is returning
`[1] "GNACNACNACNATNA"`

Any tips?

Comment: It’s best to use well tested libraries for stuff like that, e.g. [reverseComplement from Biostrings](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/Biostrings/man/Biostrings.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

There are probably many ways to do this, including dedicated genetics packages. But if you are looking for a simple base R method, you could use `chartr` for the character substitutions:

```
x = 'ACGTGTAC'
y = chartr('ATGC', 'TACG', x)
# [1] "TGCACATG"
```

we can then reverse the result:

```
intToUtf8(rev(utf8ToInt(y)))  
# [1] "GTACACGT"
```

Comment: This is perfect. But to get the **reverse complement** of the sequence, i.e. the complementary sequence with the standard 5' to 3' orientation, you must also revert the result. Example using base R: `intToUtf8(rev(utf8ToInt(dna)))`